# How to listen for browser requests with POCO and c++

Tags: c++, proxy, poco-libraries

I would like to know what Poco classes to use in listening for a browser request. This is for a proxy server. 
In general I want to open a port and wait for a request from a browser.
Please give an example as I'm quite new to Poco and C++ in general.

Comment: You already asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082599/which-poco-net-c-classes-to-use-in-creating-a-http-proxy

Comment: yes I did, but I did not get all the info that I needed, and When I asked for more, no one responded. Hence the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the HTTPTimeServer (http://pocoproject.org/docs/00100-GuidedTour.html#4) example. Basically you need:

- Poco::Util::ServerApplication. You derive from this class to host
  the server process.
- Poco::Net::ServerSocket to handle the
  socket to listen at.
- Poco::Net::HTTPServer which is in
  charge of accepting connections and
  dispatching them to
  HTTPRequestHandler derived instances.
- Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams that tell
  the server the number of threads and
  the size of the connection backlog.
- Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler. You
  derive from this class to handle
  requests.
- Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory.
  You derive from this class to create
  handler instances.
- Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest which
  contains the information in the
  request (i.e. headers, body, cookies,
  authentication).
- Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse. You
  populate an instance of this class
  with response information such as
  headers and body.